# django picture save SuspiciousFileOperation

Tags: django

{SuspiciousFileOperation}The joined path (\.\con) is located outside of the base path component (C:\ig_db\media)

The filename I try to save is 'con.soluciones' once changed to 'consoluciones' I don't get this error.
Filename can be with "." in windows.

Answer (score 0):

CON is a reserved name, from the days of MS-DOS, when CON: was used to access the computer console. Other reserved names for DOS devices include AUX, NUL, COM1-COM9, PRN, LPT1-LPT9. For some reason, those names are still reserved in Windows.7 בינו׳ 2010

OK got it